# Export All slides in Libreoffice Impress to PDF

Tags: 12.10, libreoffice

I am writing a script that could take any type of presentation and export the slides to a PDF, but if any of the slides are hidden they are not exported to the PDF. Is it possible to export all the slides in the presentation to a PDF hidden or not? Is there an option I need to enable to do this or is it just not possible?

I've found the option in the GUI, its called Export Hidden Pages, how would I configure this to be done when using a command like:

```
libreoffice --headless --convert-to pdf somePresentation.ppt
```

Comment: This isn't supported as of yet in LibreOffice check this [bug report](https://bugs.freedesktop.org/show_bug.cgi?id=58422).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move to Apache OpenOffice, then use unoconv to export to PDF and this will then be able to export PPT to PDF and include the hidden slides. To install [Apache OpenOffice](http://www.openoffice.org) follow these [instructions](http://forum.openoffice.org/en/forum/viewtopic.php?f=16&t=68). Then grab [unoconv](http://dag.wieers.com/home-made/unoconv/) from its [git repository](https://github.com/dagwieers/unoconv) as in the ubuntu software repos it requires libreoffice and the two can't be installed simultaneously.

Answer (score 1):

```
sudo apt-get install unoconv

unoconv -d presentation -f pdf *.ppt
```

worked for me using Libreoffice on Ubuntu 14.04

Answer (score 0):

Working for Ubuntu 16.04 with LibreOffice

Version: 5.1.4.2

Build ID: 1:5.1.4-0ubuntu1

> libreoffice --headless --convert-to pdf ./Your_Presentation.pptx